# Could't change Drupal 7 password in my local system?

Tags: drupal-7

I am running a Drupal 7 site in live server. While set up on my local system, I can't use my username & password (It's not working). I can't even change my admin password. Could anyone please give a solution?

Note: When it is set up on a different server it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link on how to reset drupal passwords.

http://drupal.org/node/1023428